# Are mass and energy different in black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, black-holes, mass-energy

I happened to mention the term ‘matter’ in a question about black holes recently. A friendly user told me that the Schwarzschild model is a pure vacuum solution.

This threw me somewhat.

Such a statement being true would mean that a black hole is equivalent to any region of spacetime in the vacuum state -    with maximal mass.

How is this mass distributed?

In the same way that the minimal mass of the vacuum state spacetime is distributed?

Seeing then that black holes are spherical objects do we not have to conclude that any vacuum state in total (and therefore a finite universe) would be a closed sphere?

If this conclusion is not true and vacuum state spacetime is not bound to form closed spheres, why do we say the Schwarzschild model is a pure vacuum solution?

Surely that means the spacetime of a black hole is also in its lowest possible energetic state.

That explains the energy content in the Schwarzschild model but leaves the mass unaccounted for.

Are mass and energy different in black holes?

Comment: You might be interested to read this article: https://mappingignorance.org/2019/03/25/where-is-the-mass-inside-a-black-hole/

Comment: @timm This article is completely wrong and its author is a specialist in computer science.

Comment: There are counter-arguments in the links on the page though. I think timm was providing it for general reference